# JQuery: Append to listbox - setting JSON data as value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, listbox, appendto

I'm trying to append all the selected items from listbox 1 to listbox 2, and it's working fine. The problem is that I want to set the item values of the listitems on listbox 2 to an ID i get from JSON.

I have the ID from JSON, but I'm not sure how to set the values when I use appendTo.

Here's the code I'm using now, when the values is set to "0":

```
    $('#ListBox1 option:selected').appendTo('#ListBox2');
```

I think I have to do something like this:

```
   var numberOfSelectedItems = $('#ListBox1 option:selected').length;     
   for(int i = 0; i < numberOfSelectedItems; i++)
   {
      var ID = data.array[i].ID; //This is the ID value from JSON.

      //TODO: Set the ID as value on each selected item
   }
```

Please help =)

Comment: save $('#ListBox1 option:selected') to an array and iterate that.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set use the [`.attr()` jQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to set the id on each item, perhaps combined with using Javascript's helpful [array functions](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp) to the next ID in the list.

Something like...

```
$('#ListBox1 option:selected')
    .attr('id', data.array.shift())
    .appendTo('#ListBox2');
```

JQuery allows you to chain together successive operations on a given selection, so you can set the id attribute on each before appending it to your second list.

`data.array.shift` just removes and returns the first item in the array, so each time this is called (for each list item) you'll get the next id assigned to the list item being processed.

Of course, if you need use `data.array` afterwards you may need to copy it first.

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty sure the shift-method will work, but how do I use the shift method when my array is an object? In my application, data is an array if objects and the ID is an attribute. Tried this but didn't worked: `data.array.ID.shift()`

Comment: It's just `data.array.shift().ID`.